# Reassign keywords in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Not sure quite how to word this question. I was wondering if it is possible to reassign keywords in JavaScript for instance would it be possible to do something similar to the following:

```
var         = i;
i test      = 21;
i test22    = 222;
i tryThis   = "asd";
i test37    = 21;
```

This could reduce code bytes. Not quite sure if it will be useful in a production environment but it would be a nice trick.

Comment: "This could reduce code bytes" --- what would save you bytes is minification.

Comment: @Andy —It's trying to use `i` as a `var` statement.

Comment: it would make your code very difficult for anyone else to debug

Comment: first line assigns var to i and the second line uses i as var to initialize the test variable to 21;

Comment: `var test = 21;` --- my code is almost twice as short than yours. Not sure why you think you saved something.

Comment: @zerkms, now imagine you are initializing 21 variables. That will not be shorter than mine. Ill edit my question.

Comment: @MethodMan — `var test = 12, test2 = 21, and = "so on";`

Comment: `var test = 21, test22 = 222, tryThis = "asd", test37 = 21;` --- my code is still shorter `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Okay you win :P Thats true. I guess the answer is no. Thanks though guys D:

Comment: "I guess the answer is no" --- wrong. The answer is "explain your **real** issue if there is one"

Comment: There is no real issue? It was a question. It has been answered. Thanks D:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, JavaScript doesn't provide anyway to create your own keywords / operators / etc.

Comment: Thanks. Straight forward answer. Any sources for this? I know I could google. Just want to see where you get your answer from.

Comment: It's generally hard to find documentation for things that don't exist.

Comment: a little strange how @zerkms  found it then D:

Comment: @MethodMan it's not the comprehensive link: it's just a confirmation that you cannot do that using assignment operator. It does not say anything that there is no other way of doing that (even though there is no).

Comment: @MethodMan — That says what the assignment operator does. It doesn't say that JavaScript doesn't provide a way to create your own keywords / operators / etc. (Just as it doesn't say that JavaScript will make your disk drive spontaneously emit rainbows). Documentation says what things do. It rarely says what they don't do.

Comment: I didnt ask for a link to the answer. Just a source or a reference for what you were saying... Thanks though.

Comment: Wait... So youre saying JavaScript doesnt make your hdd spontaneously emit rainbows? :c